# Beagle Bone Black interrupts for optical encoder

Tags: digital-logic, embedded, interrupts, linux, beaglebone-black

I'm trying to have my optical encoder work on interrupts. I found some resources online that discuss it but they all seem to be based on an older version of debian since the files and folders in "/sys/class/gpio" are different. The article I was trying to use says to alter "/sys/class/gpio/gpio7/edge" by issuing "echo both > /sys/class/gpio/gpio7/edge" and monitor "/sys/class/gpio/gpio7/value" in the user program the interrupt is implemented in. I was wondering if anyone knows the equivalent files to alter in "Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone70"? I plan on using python w/ Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO but I wouldn't mind using C/C++ if needed. Any input or alternate method of implementing interrupts would be much appreciated.

thanks,

Link to article:

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/765810-beaglebone-black-how-to-get-interrupts-through-linux-gpio

Comment: Note that the process in the article does not use interrupts, just a callback.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to have a formal interrupt in the the user space? Or is a callback like the one in the article suitable for most applications that need interrupts?

Comment: I don't know much about BBB -- but I keep hearing that there's a microcontroller unit in that thing that is separate from the main processor that handles the OS.  It's hard to say whether the callback approach is suitable or not.  I think it would depend upon how fast your encoder is going.  It might help to provide some parameters about how fast your encoder will be ticking away.

Comment: Its the KY-040 optical encoder on a break-out board. Its kinda cheap and i haven't been able to find any formal datasheet on it. The exact frequency of its output signals depends on how fast your turning it and I haven't been able to find an approximate range anywhere online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BBB run on Sitara AM335x which already has the interface for 3 encoders, it called eQEP. The pins are probably used as GPIOs, what you would need is to locate pins of your board, then search for suitable linux driver that can use/setup those GPIOs as eQEP, then you don't need an interrupt - this method is deprecated, it was used with MCUs without a time process unit, nowdays MCUs have all those intefaces like encoder input, PWM generator, timers,...already implemented in hardware, they are very fast.
I have done a fast internet search and this might help you: https://github.com/Teknoman117/beaglebot/tree/master/encoders/patches